# Kindly share if any attribute can be set in properties file or anywhere in jmeter to update the waiting time and maximum tries to get server response

Tags: jmeter

Getting 'response code 504 - GATEWAY TIMEOUT' when run jmeter scripts in distributed mode (1 master, 2 slaves in aws - ec2 instances). Kindly share if any attribute/value can be set in properties file or anywhere in jmeter to update the waiting time and maximum tries to get server response.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are getting the response already so you don't need to change any properties as they will not have any effect. If you need to retry the request in case of receiving HTTP status code 504 follow the next steps:

1. Store response code into a JMeter Variable using [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) like:

   [image: JMeter Response Code into Variable]
2. Once done you can put your HTTP Request under the [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) and use the following condition: `${__javaScript("${code}" != "200",)}`.

   This way JMeter will retry executing the sampler until response code will not become `200`.